# Click of any button submits form.how to stop this?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to create a form which will take the user input to create a query for database. I have three buttons: **And, Or, Run**.

I am creating dynamic elements on click of buttons And and Or.[image]

The div **search_list** is the container for containing the elements.
I need the form to be submitted on click of Run.

The weird thing is, whenever I click on any button the form gets submitted. How do I stop it ? Please let me know If you need more info.

Thanks

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var count = 0;
            function loadfirst(){
                count=1;
                addFilter('');
            }
            function addFilter(flag){
                var div = document.querySelector("#search_list"); 
                tr = document.createElement("tr");
                select = document.createElement("select");
                var sear_value = document.createElement("input");
                var and_or = document.createTextNode(flag);
                tr.id='tr_'+count;
                select.id='sl_'+count;
                sear_value.id='sear_value_'+count;

                select.options.add( new Option("user id","user_id", true,true) );
                select.options.add( new Option("First name","first_name"));
                select.options.add( new Option("Last name","last_name"));
                select.options.add( new Option("Course","course"));

                sear_value.type="text";

                if(count<=1){
                    var bt_and= document.createElement("button");
                    bt_and.id='and';
                    var bt_label = document.createTextNode("And");
                    bt_and.appendChild(bt_label);
                    bt_and.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        addFilter('and');
                        return false;
                    });

                    var bt_or= document.createElement("button");
                    bt_or.id='or';
                    var bt_label = document.createTextNode("Or");
                    bt_or.appendChild(bt_label);
                    bt_or.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        addFilter('or');
                        return false;
                    }); 
                }
                else{
                    var bt_rem= document.createElement("button");
                    bt_rem.id='rem_'+count;
                    var bt_label1 = document.createTextNode("x");
                    bt_rem.appendChild(bt_label1);
                    var tr_id = 'tr_'+count;

                    bt_rem.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    var element= document.getElementById(tr_id);
                        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                        return false;
                    });
                }

                tr.appendChild(and_or);
                tr.appendChild(select);
                tr.appendChild(sear_value);
                if(count<=1){
                    tr.appendChild(bt_and);
                    tr.appendChild(bt_or);
                }
                else{
                    tr.appendChild(bt_rem);
                }
                div.appendChild(tr);

                count++;
            }

            function getFilter(){

                alert();

            }




        </script>
        </head>

        <body onload="loadfirst()">

        <span id='manage_stud_header' class= 'list_header'>

            <label><?php echo $module_name;?></label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <center>
                <form>
                <div id='search_list' class='search'></div>
                <button id="run_filter" type="submit">Run</button>
                </form>
            </center>

        </span>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default type for buttons is "submit", so you have to explicitly say you want a plain button:

```
var bt_and= document.createElement("button");
bt_and.type = "button";
```

This way it won't submit the form when clicked. (unless of course you tell it to :))

Comment: I was such a fool. It was such a small thing, which i forgot :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

```
 <button  id = "run_filter"  type = "submit" > Run </button>
```

in

```html
 <input  id = "run_filter"  type = "submit" value="Run" />
```

and then  if the behaviour of click on button is forced to reload the page try to change button on other form element or see e.preventdefaulT of jquery